# Problema al validar un campo usando expresiones regulares

Tags: javascript

Tengo que validar un código que debe seguir este formato:

AB0123456789EX

Siendo las dos primeras letras AB, seguidas de 10 números aleatorios y terminando por dos letras aleatorias entre A y Z.

He probado con la siguiente expresión(soy novato con las expresiones regulares):

```
/^ES\[0-9]{16}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/
```

Pero no me funciona bien, doy por hecho que algo está mal, espero vuestra ayuda.

Comment: puedes usar esta gia [regex javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)

Comment: y puedes usar este [tester online](https://regexr.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de esa manera, agregando parentesis a `[0-9]` señalando un grupo, y las llaves subsiguientes serian la cantidad de veces que se repetiria esta condicion, en tu caso son 10 veces (`{10}`).

```
/^AB([0-9]){10}[a-zA-Z]{2}$/
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de gran ayuda!! Y disculpa por la tardanza en responder.